# Where does Grails/IntelliJ IDEA store .class files?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, intellij-idea, .class-file

I just can't seem to find the .class files for my Groovy source code in IntelliJ IDEA Grails projekt. I've created a grails app "qotd" and a plugin "selenium" which is kind of a grails app itself, as you might know. So just to keep things tidy here's a screenshot of my Grails View:
[Grails View](http://i12.photobucket.com/albums/a235/mhbgif/Unbenannt-3.png)

As you can see I have source code for both Java and Groovy. Both share the same package "de.it2m.testcases". Could this be a problem? Anyway, now I need to know where the .class files are stored. I've compiled both the "qotd" app and its "selenium" plugin using the "grails run-app" command without errors, so I'm sure there must be the .class files *somewhere*. I already found the class file for the "SeGridTest.java" class in:

...IntelliJ workspace\qotd\out\production\selenium-inplacePlugin\de\it2m\testcases

Unfortunately the "SeleniumTest.class" is missing in this directory (as I would have expected it there). I was browsing the ".grails" directory as well but without any success.
Where could the SeleniumTest.class hide...?

Note: I'm working on Windows 8.1 Pro, IntelliJ ultimate 13.1.4 and Grails 2.3.8

Comment: Did you try to find in target folder because all '.class' file after compilation goes there.

Comment: No, this will run the unit and integration tests.

Comment: You're right! I was looking in the "out" folder only as the Java .class file got there. Thank you! Does anybody know about the difference between the out and the target folder? Moreover I find both .class files in two different folders:
...IntelliJ workspace\qotd\selenium\target\classes\de\it2media\testcases
and
...IntelliJ workspace\qotd\target\work\plugin-classes\de\it2media\testcases

Why is that?

Comment: out is used by intellij and target is used by grails.  and the `**/work/**` dir is used internally by grails for the plugin and `**/classes/**` is used to put all together in the right place for deployment.

Comment: @cfrick I don't seem to find the `work` directory inside `target`. I checked my `BuildConfig` and that's where it's configured. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 6):

@[Tinku Saini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3568291/tinku-saini)
Thanks for your help! The .class files get into the "target" directory